# Modify background color of percentages using styleinterval

Tags: r, dt

[image]

We are using data table in R to show stats of different values. 
Some are simple points values and some are percentages, values without percentage sign (%) are colored but values with percentage sign (%) are not colored as required.

Please help us to apply colors on both type of values with and without percentage sign, Thanks in Advance.

Here is the piece of code which I am using for coloring:

```
backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(-0.000001,0.000001), c("red",'lightgrey','lightgreen'))
```

Comment: Could you provide the full code, and not only a piece, so that we can reproduce ?

Comment: return(

datatable(
table,
colnames = c("IN","OUT","Differential","Flag"),
selection = "none",

options = list(
dom = "t",
paging = F,
searching = F,
processing=FALSE,
columnDefs = list(list(targets = 4, visible = FALSE))
))%>% formatStyle(
'Differential',
backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(-0.000001,0.000001), c("red",'lightgrey','lightgreen')),
Color = styleInterval(c(-0.000001,0.000001), c("white","black","black"))
)


)

Comment: Without seeing your exact data, I would guess you need to strip the % signs off the Differential variable and set as numeric, then set the colours. Actually, I would recommend this anyway as your data indicates that the difference between IN and OUT is a % when it actually is measuring percentage points.

Comment: Hi Guys,

I am facing the same issues on Amazon server we have deployed the RStudio and everything is working fine but whenever we want to apply "styleInterval" for coloring then if there is not a numeric value then "styleInterval" not works,

I.e. We have some numeric values like 2, -3 and 3 as well as some string values like -2%, 2% and 3%, So what i observe styleInterval property is not working for string type of values. It seems on Amazon RStudio could not identify the value from string value but on local setup (RStudio on windows working fine) issues is on Amazon server

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column containing the numerical values, and use this column in the `valueColumns` argument of `formatStyle`. You also hide it with the `columnDefs` option. Here is an example:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  C1 = c("A", "B", "C"),
  C2 = c(4, "5%", "-6%")
)
dat$C2numeric <- stringr::str_extract(dat$C2, "\\-*\\d+\\.*\\d*")

datatable(dat, options = list(
  columnDefs = list(
    list(targets=-1, visible=FALSE)
  )
)) %>%
  formatStyle(2, valueColumns = ncol(dat), 
              backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(-0.000001,0.000001), c("red",'lightgrey','lightgreen')))
```